# Funcion para obtener datos con PDO

Tags: php, pdo

anteriormente tenia la siguiente funcion para obtener los datos mediante Mysqli, pero ahora me gustaria realizarlo con PDO, que cosas deberia cambiar para que funciones ?, ya que me da errores. Estaria agradecido de su orientacion.

```
public function obtenerdatos($query) {
    $query->execute();
    $datos = array();
    $query->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $query->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $metadata = $query->result_metadata();
        $parametros = array();
        while ( $campos = $metadata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $parametros[] = &$datos[$i][ $campos->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $query, 'bind_result' ), $parametros );
        $query->fetch();
    }       
    return $datos;
    $query->close();
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta mal formulada, ¿qué errores obtienes?, ¿qué si has cambiado y que aún no?

Answer (score 1):

PDO es una interfaz para acceder a la base de datos de forma más rápida y agnóstica que mysqli o sus derivadas. Lo primero que deberías hacer es crear una clase o función que llame a la instancia de PDO y la puedas rehusar, es decir, algo como esto:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);
```

Esto te dará acceso a la base de datos. Si lees la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php), te dará una perspectiva de lo amplia que puede ser esa instancia PDO y lo que puedes usar.

Si solo necesitas traer los datos, podrías hacer esto:

```
class Foo {
    public $pdo;

    public __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    static public function get($table, $options = '*') {
        $query = "SELECT {$options} FROM {$table}";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt = $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Luego estando en el archivo que quieras obtener el resultado, solo debes invocar a la clase Foo y al usar su método get y pasándole la tabla, te traerá todos los resultados. Es decir, algo como esto:

```
$values = Foo::get('users');
```